# Can I 'chain' non clustered indexes in SQL Server by including columns in other indexes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table, `my_table`, with columns `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`.

I have one query that filters on `a`, `b`, and `c` and returns `d` and `e`; I have another query that filters on `b` and `c`, and returns `d` and `e`. If I create the following indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
    ON my_table (a)
    INCLUDE (b);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
    ON my_table (b,c)
    INCLUDE (d,e);
```

Can the first query (filtering on `a`, `b`, `c`) use both indexes?

SQL Server 2008 R2, if it matters.

Comment: I dont think so (and I doubt it would be efficient), what does the SQL Query Analyzer say? Is INCLUDE(b,c) not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's called index intersection, https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/06/lets-make-match-index-intersection/ .

For this to happen however, SQL Server has to determine that each index seek cuts down on the total number of matching rows in the table, but still results in multiple rows returned, but the intersection of a seek against both again significantly reduces the number of matching rows in the table versus a seek against only one.

Since I'm assuming your real question is if you should create yet a third index to handle this query with reasonable performance, my general answer would be no, you should not. Index intersection would most likely be a possibility for SQL Server to use in the worst case scenario where a lookup against just one index does not filter the rows significantly enough to justify the bookmark lookups.

There is a situation where the third index could be beneficial, if and only if the result of a seek against both of the current indexes returned a large percentage of the table rows, yet the intersection of the two results is very small. For SQL Server to pump that many rows from two branches and match row to row would possibly be much heavier than a single seek into a single index to return very few rows. Only you would know your data that well, but it seems unlikely, and would most likely mean that your two existing indexes are not currently selective enough to be used for index seeks as is.

Answer (score 0):

Usually no.

I've heard that under very rare circumstances later versions of SQL Server can use multiple indexes for one operation, but the person who told me this said that he's never seen it actually happen.

Think of it this way, how would you write the code in C#?

Using just the first index, you would find your rows and then perform hashtable lookups in the clustered index for the missing data.

Using both indexes, you would find your rows in the first index and then perform full index scans using nested loops. That is to say, for each matching record from the index (out loop), you would looping over every record in the second index looking for the match (inner/nested loop).

Or using both indexes, you would find all the rows in the first index and all of the rows in the second index. Then you would have to figure out how to join the two lists according go the primary key, probably using nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what indexes it will use just given a two queries and the columns they look at. Index usage is entirely based on statistics and the execution plan is built around that. Even if you have an index, on a small enough table you will get index scans instead of seeks simply because it doesn't save time or reads to do the seek over the scan.

To tell which indexes it would use you would need to know a) how big the table is b) how unique a,b,c individually are c) the estimated/actual execution plan based on b). That determines your index usage. The server will use whatever plan it thinks will get your results the fastest.

For the server to generate the execution plan Jonathan described above to happen, it would take a fairly specific dataset. Unique (or practically unique) a,b,c's to make the indexes worth using, a deep AND wide table which would discourage a key lookup. And of course, the statistics would need to actually represent that to make the execution plan consider using both indexes.